# Non-Persistence Field

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I have `Items` table :

```
Id Code   Quantity
1  Cake01 10
2  Cake02 15
3  Cake03 20

public class Items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

`Orders` table :

```
Id ItemsId Quantity
1  1       5
2  1       3
3  2       10
4  3       2
5  3       5
6  1       2

public class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemsId { get; set; }
    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

How I get remaining quantity in MVC 5? Normally, I just create view like this :

```
select a.Id, a.Quantity-(isnull(b.Quantity,0)) as Remaining 
from Items a left join
(select ItemsId as Id, sum(Quantity) as Quantity group by ItemsId) as b
on a.Id = b.Id
```

Result :

```
Id Remaining
1  1
2  5
3  10
```

Is it possible to create non-persistance field in MVC 5? I have searching about this and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each `Order` will have an Item associated with it via the `ItemsId` forigen key and `Items` navigational property, you should add Orders collection property to your `Items` entity.

```
public class Items
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Orders> Orders { set; get; }
}
```

Now can use a LINQ query to get the remaining quantity for each Item. I would create a view model/DTO to represent this data.

```
public class ProductVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Code { set; get; }
    public int RemainingQuantity { set; get; }
}
```

Now in your LINQ query, get the Items, get the sum of Quantity from each Item's Orders collection and subtract that from the Quantity property value.

```
var products = db.Items
                 .Select(p => new ProductVm
                               {
                                  Id = p.Id,
                                  Code = p.Code,
                                  RemainingQuantity = p.Quantity - p.Orders
                                                                    .Sum(n => n.Quantity)
                               }).ToList();
```

Here the type of `products` will be `List<ProductVm>`.

Comment: Thank you alot, this collection I am looking for.

Comment: hi there, is it possible to make `ProductVM` static object like View in SQL Server? So I just need access `ProductVM` like normal object without do the LINQ query every time accessing it? thank you.

Comment: ProductVm is a class. you can use it wherever you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I mean I want to try like this `public int RemainingQuantity {  get { return this.Quantity - this.Orders.Sum( n => n.Quantity); } }` Is it possible?

Comment: You can if you want. You may create the View model class structure similar to your entity class (with a view model for the the Order which will be used as the Orders collection type in your ProductVm) and do that. You need to read the entity and populate the ProductVm object. But Why you want to do that ? The above will give you the data you want.

Comment: because I use it in many controllers, I dont know if doing it in models is good practice but when I change the criteria, it will bothersome to change it in all controllers. Im trying to do it in identical view models but still doesn't works. Im thnking about making a dbContext in this view models, but is it good practice?

Comment: IMHO, View models should be simple DTOS. Do not mix your dbcontext inside view models. You may use your dbContext to read entity, map to your view models and use that(That is exactly what we did in the answer)

Comment: HI there, I have problem when `p.Orders.Sum(n => n.Quantity)` is `NULL`, I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975288