# IsNull in LINQ Sum()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have problem with IsNull in LINQ :

```
db.WarehouseInputsDetails
    .Select(p => new WarehouseInputDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id
        RemainingQuantity = p.Quantity - p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity)
    }).AsQueryable();
```

`p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity)` possibility `NULL`. I want to have result like this :

`select Id, IsNull(Sum(Quantity),0) as Quantity from LoadingsDetails`

I have tried something like :

```
db.WarehouseInputsDetails
    .Select(p => new WarehouseInputDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id
        RemainingQuantity = p.LoadingDetails.First() == null ? p.Quantity : p.Quantity - p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity)
    }).AsQueryable();
```

It return errors :

> System.NotSupportedException: The method 'First' can only be used as a
>   final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in
>   this instance instead.

I have tried something like this :

```
db.WarehouseInputsDetails
    .Select(p => new WarehouseInputDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id
        RemainingQuantity = (p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity) == DBNull.Value) ? p.Quantity : p.Quantity - p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity)
    }).AsQueryable();
```

**OR**

```
db.WarehouseInputsDetails
    .Select(p => new WarehouseInputDetailsViewModel
    {
        Id = p.Id
        RemainingQuantity = p.LoadingsDetails.First().Quantity == DBNull.Value ? p.Quantity : p.Quantity - p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity)
    }).AsQueryable();
```

Return Errors :

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'DBNull'

[image]

Comment: why don't you check `p.LoadingDetails.First() != null` inside `Where()` ?

Comment: @MohamadArmoon because it is `LEFT JOIN`, I want to have `p.Quantity` if the `RIGHT` table `IS NULL`

Comment: What is null ? `p.LoadingsDetails` or `n.Quantity` in your LINQ expression ? Share the relevant parts of your entity class definition

Comment: @Shyju : `p.LoadingsDetails`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Any()` here which will check if there is any row for `LoadingDetails`, if yes then Sum the `Quantity` for `LoadingDetails`:

```
RemainingQuantity = p.LoadingDetails.Any()  ? 
                p.Quantity - p.LoadingsDetails.Sum(n => n.Quantity) : 
                p.Quantity
```